# Error while trying to save full map as .pcd or keyframes

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd, pcd, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a problem with ccny_rgbd: everything run smooth and in real time,
but everytime I call the save_pcd_map service I get this error:

```
ERROR: service [/save_pcd_map] responded with an error: [pcl::PCDWriter::writeBinary] Error during open!
```

Instead with save_keyframes service I get the following error:

```
ERROR: service [/save_keyframes] responded with an error: boost::filesystem::create_directory: No such file or directory: "~/my_keyframe_sequence/0000"
```

I'm running it under ubuntu 12.10 and ros-groovy, any advice is welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60504/error-while-trying-to-save-full-map-as-.pcd-or-keyframes/) by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apologies for the late answer

This error occurs when the program cannot create the directory. I'm not sure whether the boost function I use plays nice with the "~" character. Try it will the full path.

The other problem could be that the directory exists already.

It's not very clean behavior - feel free to opn a ticket and I'll try to revise it.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0